# How can I set 2D array data to a range?

Tags: maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I know how to append 2D array to a sheet from a brand new row.

But in my situation, I need to set the 2D array data to the range "B1:G3" below.

2D array data:

```
[
   ["2018-01","2018-02","2018-03",....,"2018-12","Total"],
   [100,200,300,....,400,2000],
   [10,20,33,....,44,300]
]
```

[image: img1]

How it can be done.
By the way, I use maatwebsite/excel 2.1.0

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found this in the source code of Laravel Excel.

I can use below:

```
$sheet->fromArray($2DArrayData, null, 'B1', true, false);
```

parameters meanning:

```
    /**
 * Fill worksheet from values in array
 *
 * @param array       $source               Source array
 * @param mixed       $nullValue            Value in source array that stands for blank cell
 * @param bool|string $startCell            Insert array starting from this cell address as the top left coordinate
 * @param boolean     $strictNullComparison Apply strict comparison when testing for null values in the array
 * @param bool        $headingGeneration
 * @throws PHPExcel_Exception
 * @return LaravelExcelWorksheet
 */
public function fromArray($source = null, $nullValue = null, $startCell = 'A1', $strictNullComparison = false, $headingGeneration = true)
{
```